# What does ` UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY <packageName> extraneous` mean?

Tags: npm

I understand that `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` means I need to `npm install` one of my `peerDependencies`. I *believe* that `extraneous` means the package exists but is not listed in `package.json` (presumably because it's installed globally?).

What does it mean to have the two of them together?

And why am I seeing this error even though I see these packages in `node_modules`, at the correct versions?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It means that you have a module installed in your local npm repo that is "extraneous" (meaning you have no dependency on it) that has an "unmet peer dependency" on a library you also do not have installed (or if you do have it installed locally or globally, it is also extraneous so it's not in your dependency tree). If you run `npm prune` it should remove the extraneous dependency and this message.

Comment: Even if I locally install those dependencies I still get the same error. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: They have to be in your dependencies, not just in your modules directory. Running a prune or installing with --save should fix it